# Why they use the word "abstract" for naming mathematical fields of study?

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, terminology

I've found some books with titles such as *abstract analysis* - but I don't understand why they choose such word. For me it seems quite vague and perhaps misleading - consider the examples:

- *Real* Analysis
- *Complex* Analysis

In this case, it seems to be clear what they are dealing with: *Real* and *Complex* numbers and also some structures that emerges from them. I've already seen books that were called *abstract analysis* and covered *real* and *complex* analysis and also other books that  had the same name and covered measure theory. It's the same for abstract algebra but in this case, it seems to be fixed to concepts such as rings, fields, monoids, etc.

This question may be an invite to a discussion, but it is not: I am really trying to understand what's the usage of the word *abstract* - I'm not really sure if it's really employed in this vague broad sense or if there's something I still don't know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word *abstract* when referring to fields of study in mathematics is always used in a vague sense which is not too precise. It simply means that the study is based on the abstract properties of the structure, say the group axioms, so that it applies to all groups and not just a concrete group like the integers under addition. By convention in the mathematical literature, *abstract algebra* is used to refer to the study of groups, rings and fields and the like.

The term *abstract analysis* is less commonly used and appears for example in the title of the well-known book *Real and Abstract Analysis* by Hewitt and Stromberg. This refers to us not just studying the real numbers but objects like function spaces in an axiomatic manner. Hewitt and Ross wrote another book, *Abstract Harmonic Analysis*, which studies harmonic analysis on topological groups instead of just classical fourier analysis on euclidean spaces.